# Not showing location on Google map

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I have an address and want to show that address on Google map. The map is showing but does not point to that particular address. Here is my code. I am getting this error: `couldn't get connection factory client`.

```
private MapController mc;
private MapView mapView;
GeoPoint p;
private MyOverlays mapOverlay;
mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.myMapView);
mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
  try {
    List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(loc, 5);
    if (addresses.size() > 0) {
      p = new GeoPoint(
        (int) (addresses.get(0).getLatitude() * 1E6),
        (int) (addresses.get(0).getLongitude() * 1E6));
      mc.animateTo(p);
      mapView.invalidate();
    }
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  if (p != null) {
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    mapOverlay = new MyOverlays(drawable, this);
    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(p, "", "");
    mapOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    mapView.getOverlays().add(mapOverlay);
    this.mc = this.mapView.getController();
    this.mc.setCenter(this.p);
    this.mc.setZoom(16);
  }
  // LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
  // lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000L, 500.0f, (LocationListener) this);
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have provided below permissions in android **Manifest**
 
    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`
    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>`

You need to activate GPS on your test device. If you test on the emulator and its not activated you get "null" if you try to use a *`LocationManager`*.

The Google Map Activity should automatically activate the GPS device in the emulator but if you want to use the location manager directly you need to do this yourself. 
[Using GPS and setting location](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should test your code on device not on emulator.

Dont know why but there is some problem in emulator.

In my case it was working properly on device but give same error on emulator.

Comment: which exception? [see in log cat]

Comment: 06-01 13:26:56.004: E/MapActivity(305): Couldn't get connection factory client

Comment: I think it is not problem with your code this problem keep persisting. see issue
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8816

check it > 
       proper permission in manifest
       internate avail